# flutter: I want to click plot chart and show data on charts_flutter

Tags: flutter, charts, scatter-plot

I want to show data when i clicked dot plot chats

like this (for example i use SfCircularChart but i want to use Scatter it's not free for SfCircularChart ,So I had to build it myself):

> My code result this:

[image]

> I want this:

[image]

this is my code:

```
class SimpleScatterPlotChart extends StatelessWidget {
  List<charts.Series<_HeartRateData, num>> seriesList;
  final bool animate;
  SimpleScatterPlotChart({required this.seriesList, this.animate = false});
  factory SimpleScatterPlotChart.withSampleData() {
    return new SimpleScatterPlotChart(
      seriesList: _createSampleData(),
      animate: false,
    );
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 250,
      width: 350,
      child: new charts.ScatterPlotChart(
        seriesList,
        animate: animate,
        primaryMeasureAxis: new charts.NumericAxisSpec(
        renderSpec: new charts.GridlineRendererSpec(
        labelStyle: new charts.TextStyleSpec(
          color: charts.Color.fromHex(code: '#7A7A7A')
        ),
      )
  ),
        //primaryMeasureAxis: new charts.NumericAxisSpec(renderSpec: new charts.NoneRenderSpec()),
        domainAxis: charts.NumericAxisSpec(
          showAxisLine: false,
          renderSpec: charts.NoneRenderSpec(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  /// Create one series with sample hard coded data.
  static List<charts.Series<_HeartRateData, num>> _createSampleData() {
    return [
      new charts.Series<_HeartRateData, num>(
        id: 'Sales',
        colorFn: (_HeartRateData sales, _) {
          //final bucket = sales.heartRate / maxMeasure;

          if (sales.heartRate < 61) {
            return charts.Color.fromHex(code: '#F8D277');
          } else if (sales.heartRate < 100) {
            return charts.Color.fromHex(code: '#61D2A4');
          } else {
            return charts.Color.fromHex(code: '#DD5571');
          }
        },
        domainFn: (_HeartRateData sales, _) => sales.date,
        measureFn: (_HeartRateData sales, _) => sales.heartRate,
        radiusPxFn: (_HeartRateData sales, _) => sales.radius,
        data: apiData,
      ),
    ];
  }
}
```